# Market place test failed PhoneApplicationService

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I'm trying to pass my application to Microsoft market place, however I'm having 3 error in my background agent, that I don't understand.

Is says:

```
 Unsupported API cannot be used by a background agent. Assembly contoso.dll was trying to 
use Micosoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService::get_Current 

Unsupported API cannot be used by a background agent. Assembly contoso.dll was trying to 
use Micosoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService::get_State

Unsupported API cannot be used by a background agent. Assembly contoso.dll was trying to 
use Micosoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService
```

So I've looked for unsupported API (`http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962(v=vs.105).aspx`)

I'm using `ShellToast` class but it's supposed to be supported ??

I don't understand why or when I'm using this PhoneApplicationService, it is not referenced in my background agent, and the only class I'm using in the `Microsoft.Phone.Shell` namespace is `ShellToast`...

Also I'm using IsoStorage but it's allowed from background agent

Any guess without the code? Do you know when this errors could fires up ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I'm stupid I've found the solution.

Indeed it was not my `ShellToast` class, but my TempDataStorage which use `PhoneApplicationService.Current.State` for temporary storage.

Sorry 'bout that